# Connection between Oracle database and C#

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I'm trying to create simple log in page with visual studio win form. I have got username and password as textbox controls.

here is the event which should check if there is such kind of user in database:

```
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select staff_username, staff_password from staff_accounts";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                if (username.Text == dr["staff_username"].ToString() && pass.Text == dr["staff_password"].ToString())
                {
                    admin.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = "Error";
                }
            }
        }
```

`dr.HasRows` returns false, so it means that `cmd.CommandText = "select staff_username, staff_password from staff_accounts";` returns no rows, but in my database the same query works fine.

any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? Please post what exception you are getting ?

Comment: No exception pops up. Simply nothing happens

Comment: it should either open new form or change label1 text value to error

Comment: I guess it's cause of cmd.CommandText... when it's assigned to "select 5+1 from dual" for example it works, but when it's assigned to "select staff_username, staff_password from staff_accounts" it returns no rows

Comment: I have checked it in my database,it seems fine there. it returns everything

Comment: Wild thought... Oracle requires that statements end with a semicolon, right? Your `CommandText` value doesn't have one. Maybe it's waiting for more command text or the semicolon.

Comment: I have added semicolon... Exception popped up- ORA-00911:invalid character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check `HasRows` property before calling reader `Read()` method. Try:

```
 if (dr.HasRows)
 {
   while (dr.Read())
   {
     ....
```

Comment: Even better, just don't check `HasRows` at all. In the event of an empty result set, `Read` will return `false`, skipping the loop altogether.

Comment: @Alejandro, I totally agree, but I just leave hasRows check since OP uses it